# Can I install Ubuntu 16.04 without damaging Windows 10 in a dual-boot?

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade

I had Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my laptop before. Because there were some problems, I upgraded it to Ubuntu 15.10, unfortunately the upgrade didn't complete(even though Ubuntu can boot).

I wonder could I just install Ubuntu 16.04 to replace 15.10 without damaging Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a previous installation of Ubuntu you can instruct the Ubuntu installer to use its partition(s). That means that the installer won't need to touch the Windows partitions, so there's only a minuscule chance that the installation accidentally alters Windows despite that fact. You'll need to use [manual partitioning during installation](/q/343268/175814) though.

As always, make a back-up anyhow. Data without back-up is unimportant data by definition.

Comment: When I installed Ubuntu 14.04, I selected "INSTALL ALONG SIDE OF WINDOWS 8 (upgraded to Win 10 later)", rather than "SOMETHING ELSE". Could I select "INSTALL ALONG SIDE OF WINDOWS 10" when I install Ubuntu 16.04, so I don't have to do "manual partitioning"?

Comment: I don't think so. The installer has 3 options: 1) remove everything and install Ubuntu, 2) shrink the Windows partition and install Ubuntu in the freed space (only works if you have a single partition with Windows and nothing else), and 3) manual partitioning ("something else").

Comment: So I should remove the existing Ubuntu 15.10 first, then install a new version, right? How should I remove Ubuntu 15.10, is it different from the uninstallation which used manual partition when installed?

Comment: The partition manager of the Ubuntu installer lets you format existing partitions if you want to get rid of their previous content.

Comment: So I don't have to do the uninstallation. Thanks, I am gonna try!

Comment: There's no "uninstallation" for operating systems. You just delete/overwrite their files and/or partitions and replace their boot loader with that of a different OS.